# ¿Cómo utilizar listas dentro de una función en Python?

Tags: python

He creado dos listas en Python (l1,l2):

```
#lista 1 longitudes x for x in range (0,100) 
#lista 2 radios i for i in range (1,10)
```

Y quiero usar el primer valor de la lista 1, con todos los valores de la lista 2. Al terminar pasar con el segundo valor de la lista 1, y pasar por todos los valores de la lista 2, así hasta acabar con el total.
Ahora, la relación que necesito usar se va a llamar volumen

```
Volumen = (pi)(radio**2)(longitud) 
#Guardar el valor en algún documento externo
```

No se si sea posible, en fortran solía hacerlo con un Do anidado.

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias

Comment: pues si es posible, por ejemplo haciendo `(alguna_funcion(x,lista2) for x in lista1)`. Daría una respuesta pero hacen falta varios detalles de lo que quieres hacer

Comment: ¿Podrías escribir código _real_ de lo que tienes de momento? Lo que has escrito es una especie de pseudocódigo que no sería ejecutable por Python. Por otro lado me da la sensación de que lo que estás buscando no es más que un `for` dentro de otro `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto puede ayudarte. Podrías usar for (como comentabas) de la siguiente manera y guardarlo internamente para después devolver una lista con los valores finales de volumen.

```
import math
longitudes = [10,20,30]
radio = [40,50,60]
    
def devolverListaConVolumenes(l1,l2):
    devolverVolumenes = []
    pi = math.pi # valor pi librería math
    for lo in l1: # lista 1
        for ra in l2: # lista 2
            volumen = pi*(ra**2)*lo
        devolverVolumenes += [volumen]
    return devolverVolumenes # Devuelve lista con volúmenes
```

### Ahora lanzamos un print() con la función para ver los resultados.

```
print(devolverListaConVolumenes(longitudes,radio))
```

Tener en cuenta que es Python y la indentación de la función `devolverListaConVolumenes()` debe ser la correcta.

Comentame que tal fue todo.
Saludos.

Comment: Revisa la indentación del código, creo que es incorrecta

Comment: @abulafia , Ahora corregí al indentado correcto dentro de stackOverflow . Gracias!